# CI - show me what went wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've developed a simple login system which works OK but fails, and I need to know why.

QUESTION: How to show what is causing the fail?

Here's the database function:

```
function login($email,$password)
{
    $this->db->where("email",$email);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);

    $query=$this->db->get("users");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id'  => $rows->id,
                'user_name'  => $rows->username,
                'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                'logged_in'  => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's the logic:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->signin();
    }
    else
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=md5($this->input->post('pass'));
        $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
        if($result)
        {
            $this->dash();
        }
        else
        {
            $data['title']= 'Login Error';
            $this->load->view('nav/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('login', $data);
            $this->load->view('nav/footer', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the error is happening as I redirect back to the login page if it fails and change the title text to show me (only in testing mode for right now). But how can I find out what is going wrong?

This is the check database function:

```
function login($email,$password)
{
    $this->db->where("email",$email);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);

    $query=$this->db->get("users");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id'  => $rows->id,
                'user_name'  => $rows->username,
                'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                'logged_in'  => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why you paste model code twice?

Comment: side note : do not apply `trim` rule  while password validation

Comment: you change the question completely. ask another one and retain the older one.

Answer (score 0):

write below code in your **view** file

```
<section id="notification" >
<?php
      if(validation_errors() !== '' ) { 
         echo "<div class='alert-msg error'>";
         echo validation_errors();
         echo "</div>";
      }
      $error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
      $success = $this->session->flashdata('success');
      if($error)
      {
        echo "<div class='alert-msg error'>";
        echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
        echo "</div>";
      }

      if($success)
      {
        echo "<div class='alert-msg success'>";
        echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
        echo "</div>";
      }
  ?>
</section>
```

and set success/error message conditionally in flash data in **controller** ( see below)

```
 if($result) {
    $this->dash();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Login successfully.');
 } else {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Login failed');
 }
```

Read more [Flashdata in CI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Thanks but its not validation error - its db error - will update question

Answer (score 0):

I assume all your php code is fine, then what you need is set custom [form-validation-message](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors) for each input to know which input went wrong and echo them:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your changed answer:

use below logic in your model

```
 $qry = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $this->_username ));
 if ($qry->num_rows() == 1) {           
    $user = $qry->row_array();
    $submitted_pass = md5($this->_password);
    $db_pass = $user['password'];
    if ($submitted_pass === $db_pass) {
        return $user;
    } else {
        // wrong username/password
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->errorList[10]);
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    // no such username exist     
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->errorList[15]);
    return FALSE;
}
```