# Echo mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using the following function in a model:

```
function login($email,$password)
{
    $this->db->where("email",$email);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);

    $query=$this->db->get("users");

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id'  => $rows->id,
                'user_name'  => $rows->username,
                'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                'logged_in'  => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    } else { 

    }
    return false;
}
```

When I enter the details it should not fail. There is no db error, I have debug turned on.

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to echo the query that is being sent so I can see what its trying to do and thus why its failing.

Comment: maybe in the db class you can echo the query before the execute_query statement

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements/210693#210693

Comment: I have downvoted your question because you have posted it 3 times:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478481/ci-show-database-error-or-fail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477979/ci-show-me-what-went-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes..

try this

```
 echo $this->db->last_query();
```

after you make a  query....

this print the query that was last made..

so if you want to get the last query,do

```
 $query=$this->db->get("users");
 echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: Perfect! many thanks, will accpet asap

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

And see the query.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
print_r($query);
```

after

```
$query=$this->db->get("users");
```

Comment: this won't print the query... have you tried this....